# EF fluent mapping DbGeography issue: The type 'System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T'

Tags: .net, entity-framework, geolocation, spatial, ef-fluent-api

Entity:

```
public Geography Location { get; set; }
```

Mapping:

```
 this.Property(a => a.Location)
            .IsRequired();
```

Any good solution for this? I can see this is duplication for already opened questions but there is no good answer on what is it and how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

Instead of using System.Data.Spatial I used EntityFramework (assembly) System.Data.Entity.Spatial:

```
public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
```

I hope this helps someone else.